# Custom Post Type Single Page is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I wanted to know, why my single custom post type isn't working.
Everytime I wanted to open the single post type it automatically gets back to the homepage.

Please help!

Here is my code:

```php
// Team im Backend hinzufügen

function register_team() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Team', 'team' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Team', 'team' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Neues Mitglied', 'team' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Neues Mitglied', 'team' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Mitglied bearbeiten', 'team' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Neues Mitglied', 'team' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Zeige Mitglied', 'team' ),
        'all_items' => 'Alle Mitglieder',
        'search_items' => __( 'Suche Mitglied', 'team' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Keine Mitglied gefunden', 'team' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Kein Mitglied im Papierkorb gefunden', 'team' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Übergeordnetes Mitglied:', 'team' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Team', 'team' ),
        'public' => true,
        
        
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'team',
        //'slug' => 'portfolio',
        'with_front' => true,
        'pages' => true,
        'feeds' => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', ),
        //'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        'capability_type' => 'page', 'post'
    );
    
    //register_post_type( 'products', $args );
    register_post_type( 'team', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_team' );


// Custom Taxonomie für Team hinzufügen (wie Kategorien)
function add_team_taxonomies() {
  register_taxonomy('teamtaxo', 'team', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x( 'Team Kategorie', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Team Kategorie', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Kategorie' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Kategorie' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Kategorie' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Kategorie:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Kategorie' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Kategorie' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Kategorie' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Kategorie Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Team Kategorie' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'team', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
      'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
      'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_team_taxonomies', 0 );
```

This is my team category site:
`https://test.musikschulegraz.at/team-testseite/`

And I can't click on 'mehr lesen...' without getting back to my homepage?

Thank you!

Comment: You used `'team'` as a slug in a rewrite for CPT and for taxonomy. For this reason, post links as well as taxonomy (terms) links are recognized as term links. Use different slugs and the problem should go away.

Comment: Hello @Buttered_Toast ! Thanks for your answer! I have a new stack overflow - account, so don't worry about it. Okay and how can I get my costum post type single page? :-) Cause now, it's empty? Thanks for helping!